# Несколько потоков используют один ObjectInputStream и возникает ошибка java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00

Tags: java

Возникла задача написания сетевого чата на сокетах. Имеется сервер, который в бесконечном цикле ожидает подключение от клиентов. При подключении клиента он создает для него отдельный поток обмена данными вот его код:
package serverapp;

import clientapp.Message;
import clientapp.Wrapper;
import clientapp.Client;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.List;
//сервер
public class ServerApp {
    ObjectOutputStream out; //выходной поток, который будет добавляться в массив clientOutputStreams
    ArrayList clientOutputStreams; //список потоков
    ArrayList listClients; //список зарегистрированных пользователей

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   new ServerApp().go();//запускаем сервер
}

public void go(){
    clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();
    listClients = new ArrayList<Client>(); //инициализируем списки

    //при запуске сервера считываем из файла данные о предыдущих регистрациях
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("temp.out");
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        listClients = (ArrayList<Client>) oin.readObject(); //считываем данные 

        //если массив не пустой то создаем количество выходных потоков в таком же количестве как количество зарегистрированных пользователей
        if(!listClients.isEmpty()){

            for(int i = 0; i < listClients.size(); i++){
                clientOutputStreams.add(null);
            }
            //стандартный вывод в окно отладки о количестве зарегистрированных пользователей
            System.err.println("В сети зарегистрированы " + listClients.size() + " клиент(ов):");
            for(int i = 0; i < listClients.size(); i++){
                System.err.println(i+1 + ") " + listClients.get(i).getLogin());
            }
        }
        else{
            System.err.println("В сети нет зарегистрированных пользователей");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Не удалось загрузить файл temp.out");
    }

    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while (true) {                
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); //ждем подключения

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            //если клиент подключился создаем для него отдельный поток, в который передаем сокет и out-ObjectOutputStream
            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket, out));
            t.start();
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {

    }
}
class ClientHandler implements Runnable{
    ObjectInputStream in; 
    Socket sock;

    ObjectOutputStream outStream; 
    int index; //индекс текушего outStream в массиве clientOutputStreams

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket, ObjectOutputStream out){
        try{
            sock = clientSocket;
            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            outStream = out;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void run(){
        Wrapper o = null; 
        try {
            //ожидаем различные данные от клиентов
            while ((o = (Wrapper)in.readObject()) != null)
            {
                //если пользователь хочет войти как зарегистрированный то
                if(o.getMarker().equals("ENTRANCE")){
                    checkClient(o.getClient()); //проверяем имеется ли он в массиве listClients
                }
                //если пользователь хочет зарегистрироваться 
                else if(o.getMarker().equals("REGISTRATION")){
                    Client newClient = o.getClient(); // то получаем от него логин и пароль
                    //проверяем зарегистрирован ли такой пользователь в сети, если имя уникально то
                    if(checkValidation(newClient)){
                        newClient.setStatus(true); //устанавливаем новому клиенту статут онлайн
                        listClients.add(newClient); //добавляем в список зарегистрированных пользователей
                        clientOutputStreams.add(outStream); //добавляем текущий outStream в clientOutputStream
                        index = listClients.size()-1; //запоминаем индекс текущего потока для clientOutputStream
                        System.out.println("'" + newClient.getLogin() + "' " + "был зарегистрирован");
                        //отправляем клиенту сообщение о том, что он может войти 
                        sendMarker("CANENTRANCE");
                    }
                    //если имя не уникально
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Отказано в регистрации для " + "'" + newClient.getLogin() + "'" );
                        //отпраляем клиенту сообщение о том, что он не может зарегистрироваться 
                        sendMarker("NOTREGISRATED");

                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //при отключении пользователя сохраняем listClients в файл
            saveData();
            System.out.println("'" + listClients.get(index).getLogin() + "'" + " вышел");
        }
    }
    //проверяем уникальность имени
    private boolean checkValidation(Client client){
        if(!listClients.isEmpty()){
            for(int i = 0; i < listClients.size(); i++){
                if(listClients.get(i).getLogin().equals(client.getLogin())){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
    //сериализуем listClient в файл temp.out
    private void saveData(){
        try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp.out");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(listClients);
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Не удалось сохранить данные в файл temp.out");
            }
    }
    //проверка наличия пользователя в списке зарегистрированных клиентов
    private void checkClient(Client client){
        boolean isRegistered = false;
        if(listClients.isEmpty()){
            sendMarker("NOTREGISRATED");
        }
        else{
            //идем по всему списку
            for(int i = 0; i < listClients.size(); i++){
                //если нашли совпадение то
                if(listClients.get(i).getLogin().equals(client.getLogin()) && listClients.get(i).getPassword().equals(client.getPassword()))
                {
                    isRegistered = true;
                    clientOutputStreams.set(i, outStream); 
                    index = i; // запоминаем индекс
                    System.out.println("'" + listClients.get(i).getLogin() + "'" + " вошел");
                    //говорим клиенту о том, что он может войти
                    sendMarker("CANENTRANCE");
                }
            }
            if(!isRegistered){
                sendMarker("NOTREGISRATED");
            }
        }
    }
    //отправляет системные сообщения клиентам
    private void sendMarker(String marker){
        try {
            out.writeUnshared(new Wrapper(marker));
            out.reset();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Не удалось отправить сообщение клиенту");
        }
    }
}
```

}
Код сервера максимально закомментирован для наглядности там должно быть все понятно.
Для обмена любыми данными между сервером и клиентом используется класс обертка, который в последствии будет улучшен, так же он передает различные системные сообщения. Вот его код:

package clientapp;

import java.io.Serializable;
//обертка для других классов
public class Wrapper implements Serializable{
    String marker; //системное сообщение
    Client client; //клиент
    //перегруженный конструктор
    public Wrapper(Client client,String marker){
        this.marker = marker;
        this.client = client;
    }
    public Wrapper(String marker){
        this.marker = marker;
    }
    //получаем системное сообщение
    public String getMarker(){
        return marker;
    }
    //получаем клиента
    public Client getClient(){
        return client;
    }
}

И собственно сам клиент состоит из окна входа, окна регистрации и самого чата
Окно входа:
public class RegWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Socket sock; // сокет
    ObjectInputStream in;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    Client client;
    Thread readerThread; //поток который будет принимать данные с сервера

```
public RegWindow() {
    initComponents();
    SetUpNetworking();
    //создаем поток на считывание данных от сервера
    readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    readerThread.start();

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(960, 300, 0, 0));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Логин");

    jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField1.setText("user");
    jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Пароль");

    jPasswordField1.setText("1234");

    jButton1.setText("Войти");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Регистрация");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 119, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 48, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        
//устанавливаем соединение
private void SetUpNetworking() {
    try{
        sock = new Socket("192.168.1.37",5000);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("networking established");
    } catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Не удалось подключиться к серверу");
    }
}
public class IncomingReader implements Runnable{

    public synchronized void run(){
        Wrapper o;
        try{  
            while((o = (Wrapper)in.readObject()) != null){
                //если сервер говорит клиенту, что таких данных как у него не найдено listClient, то показать всплывающее окно
                if(o.getMarker().equals("NOTREGISRATED")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Вы неправильно ввели логин или пароль", "Ошибка входа", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
                //если сервер нашел пользователя с такими данными то создать окно чата
                else if(o.getMarker().equals("CANENTRANCE")){
                    new ClientWindow(sock,in,out).setVisible(true);
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //System.out.println("RegWindow");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

//КНОПКА ВХОДА
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //считываем логин и пароль из textboxОВ
    client = new Client(jTextField1.getText(), jPasswordField1.getText());
    try {
        //Отправляем данные на сервер для проверки
        out.writeUnshared(new Wrapper(client, "ENTRANCE"));
        out.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Не удалось отправить логин и пароль на сервер");
    }
}                                        
//КНОПКА РЕГИСТРАЦИИ
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //если пользователь хочет зарегистрироваться создаем окно регистрации
    //и !!! передаем в него sock, in и out из текущего класса
    new Registration(sock,in,out).setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);

}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RegWindow.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new RegWindow().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}
При нажатии на кнопку зарегистрироваться, открывается окно регистрации, которое получает тот же сокет, ObjectOutputStream и ObjectInputStream, что и окно входа.
Вот код окна регистрации.
package clientapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Registration extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
Socket socket;
ObjectInputStream in;
ObjectOutputStream out;
//конструктор 
public Registration(Socket socket, ObjectInputStream in, ObjectOutputStream out) {
    initComponents();
    this.socket = socket;
    this.in = in;
    this.out = out;

    Thread readerThread = new Thread(new Registration.IncomingReader1());
    readerThread.start();
}
public class IncomingReader1 implements Runnable{

    public void run(){
        Wrapper o;
        try{  
            //считываем данные, которые отправляет сервер к окну регистрации
            while((o = (Wrapper) in.readObject()) != null){
                if(o.getMarker().equals("NOTREGISRATED")){
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Данный логин уже используется", "Ошибка регистрации", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
                //если сервер разрешил регистрацию то создаем окно чата
                else if(o.getMarker().equals("CANENTRANCE")){
                    createClientWindow();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            //System.out.println("Registration");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(new java.awt.Rectangle(960, 300, 0, 0));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Введите имя");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Введите фамилию");

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Введите логин");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("Введите пароль");

    jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField1.setText("Евгений");

    jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField2.setText("Просветов");

    jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jTextField3.setText("user");

    jButton1.setText("Зарегистрироваться");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jPasswordField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jPasswordField1.setText("1234");
    jPasswordField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(28, 28, 28)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                .addComponent(jTextField2)
                .addComponent(jTextField3)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1))
            .addContainerGap(19, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(24, 24, 24)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jLabel4)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jPasswordField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                

}                                               
//создает окно чата
private void createClientWindow(){
    new ClientWindow(socket,in,out).setVisible(true);
    this.setVisible(false);
}
//КНОПКА ЗАРЕГИСТРИРОВАТЬСЯ
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //отравляем данные на сервер для проверки валидности
    try {
        Client client = new Client(jTextField3.getText(), jPasswordField1.getText());
        out.writeUnshared(new Wrapper(client, "REGISTRATION"));
        out.reset();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Не удалось отправить данные на сервер");
    }
}                                        

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Registration.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>


}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Ошибка возникает, когда я нажимаю кнопку зарегистрироваться:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.ObjectStreamClass cannot be cast to clientapp.Wrapper
    at clientapp.Registration$IncomingReader1.run(Registration.java:31)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 00
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1381)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at clientapp.RegWindow$IncomingReader.run(RegWindow.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Я понимаю, что она скорее всего возникает из-за того, что я использую один  и тот же ObjectInputStream для всех окон, которые я запускаю. Соответственно в каждом из них запускается поток который ждет данные через один и тот же ObjectInputStream, но как исправить данную ошибку я не знаю. Не могли бы вы подсказать, что делать в данном случае?

Answer (score 2):

Проблему можно решить если поменять архитектуру клиента. Посмотрите на  паттерн MVC.

Работать с потоком (stream) должен только один объект, назовем его модель. Если приходят какие-то данные из потока, то модель уведомляет об изменениях всех кто этих изменений ждет.